# How can I have an application that is free to specific users, but paid to others

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have an application that we are building to be delivered to our users for free.  However, the business wants to be able to sell this application to anyone else who might want it.  Is there anyway we can do this?

The suggestions and concerns we've come up with are:

1. Submit app with price and deliver free download codes to users, but I believe that we only get something like 50 free download codes and we have more than 50 users.
2. Submit app for free, but make content an in-app purchase and have some mechanisim for allowing our users to validate and get the content free.  We think that Apple will hate this since the application isn't functional without the content.
3. Submit application twice, one free and one paid and just direct our users to the free one.  This means that our free version can be found and used by anyone cutting into the revenue stream.

Any suggestions/advice/hints/rants welcome.

Comment: EDIT: What about TestFlight (https://testflightapp.com/) for the free build, which would be distributed over the air, and app store for the paid version?

Comment: Re #2, you can give Apple's reviewers a login to use in testing. I did that with an app that required (at my client's design) a login before it would do anything else, and I gave a set of login creds in the review notes section, and never heard a word from Apple about it. It passed review without complaint.

Comment: Testflight still requires you to add devices to your developer account , last time we checked, and we are looking at a potential audience of 90,000 users.  It'd be way to much overhead.  We are probably going to be stuck building in an auth mechanism as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Software as a Service? The app is an extension of the service. Make the app free to anyone, but to get anything useful out of the app, require username/password or some other validation. You'd be hard pressed to find an app today that doesn't require some sort of signup process.

There are plenty of options you can go with.

In-App Purchase
Free/Lite version of App
Paid version of App

Just a matter of what you and your customers want. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, our current leading options is to add a login requirement to the "free" version.  I'm not a huge fan of having to implement client/server functionality just to validate the user on what is a stand alone application.  But what I'm a fan of doesn't really matter to the business.

Comment: Yeah. There isn't much clearly defined in this area with Apple either. So you run the risk of submitting and risking rejection, which is the boat I'm currently in. Hope you get it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a *very* basic version of the app available for free (so that Apple is happy) and then have the rest of the app "unlocked" when the user either:

1. Registers their copy of the app back with your servers (covers giving it to some for free)
2. Makes an in-app purchase to unlock the rest of the functionality

This keeps Apple happy, gives you the functions you want, and is only minimal effort.

Comment: Interesting option, doesn't really fit with the model of the application we are building, but something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

You can pay for and gift paid apps to iTunes account holders.  Making the app appear to be "Free" to those recipients.  If it's your own app, Apple will keep (only) 30% of the price you pay, so add that on to your cost of doing business.

Comment: Way too much overhead.  Not a bad idea, but we are looking at a potential "free" userbase of 90,000 with ~20,000 new potential "free" users every year.

Comment: Then you will likely need some way to differentiate a paid app or Free app IAP upgrade if you want to monitize it at all, as well as distributing it for free in such volumes.